# MySQL Performance issue with large number of rows

Tags: mysql, performance

I am developing a site based on XenForo engine, and have a problem in a query that fetches all threads and joins post table and forum table to get some information for the first post and forum the thread belongs to. The query looks like:

`SELECT thread . *

FROM xf_thread AS thread

INNER JOIN xf_node AS node ON (node.node_id = thread.node_id)

INNER JOIN xf_post AS post ON (post.post_id = thread.first_post_id)

WHERE thread.node_id IN ('295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '302', '256', '2575', '258', '259', '260', '253', '254', '255', '127', '163', '159', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '162', '171', '173', '172', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '157', '156', '158', '161', '160', '149', '227', '232', '237', '233', '236', '234', '235', '238', '248', '240', '241', '242', '239', '246', '247', '243', '244', '245', '228', '229', '230', '231', '249', '250', '251', '174', '190', '195', '199', '193', '191', '197', '198', '192', '200', '204', '207', '205', '203', '206', '202', '208', '201', '187', '176', '177', '178', '189', '188', '180', '186', '184', '185', '182', '183', '181', '179', '209', '211', '217', '218', '219', '210', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '220', '222', '223', '224', '221', '225', '261', '291', '276', '272', '270', '265', '277', '267', '286', '292', '289', '274', '264', '287', '278', '282', '279', '281', '280', '283', '284', '285', '290', '275', '268', '263', '266', '294', '262', '293', '269', '273', '288', '271')

ORDER BY thread.last_post_date DESC

LIMIT 10`

Explain results for the query are:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  node    index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    199 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  thread  ref node_id_last_post_date,node_id_sticky_last_post_date    node_id_last_post_date  4   node.node_id    221  
1   SIMPLE  post    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   thread.first_post_id    1   Using index
```

Query takes 9+ seconds to execute.

Removing joining of xf_node table, runs the query in 0.01 seconds. Explain looks like

```
id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  thread  index   node_id_last_post_date,node_id_sticky_last_post_da...   last_post_date  4   NULL    69970   Using where
1   SIMPLE  post    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   thread.first_post_id    1   Using index
```

Removing joining of xf_post table runs the query in 0.01 seconds, explain looks like

```
id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  thread  index   node_id_last_post_date,node_id_sticky_last_post_da...   last_post_date  4   NULL    70840   Using where
1   SIMPLE  node    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   thread.node_id  1   Using index
```

So, the problem exists only when both tables are joined, but joins themselves seem to be completely correct and work perfectly separately.

Number of rows in the tables - xf_thread: 71,855, xf_node: 178, xf_post: 2,977,326

My assumption is that when both tables are joined MySQL starts to use incorrect indexes, and maybe forcing an index will solve the problem?

Your help and suggestions to find a way to resolve this problem are highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here are create table statements for all tables involved

**`xf_node`**

```
CREATE TABLE `xf_node` (  
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `description` text NOT NULL,  
  `node_name` varchar(50) default NULL COMMENT 'Unique column used as string ID by some node types',  
  `node_type_id` varbinary(25) NOT NULL,  
  `parent_node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `display_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',  
  `display_in_list` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT 'If 0, hidden from node list. Still counts for lft/rgt.',  
  `lft` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Nested set info ''left'' value',  
  `rgt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Nested set info ''right'' value',  
  `depth` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Depth = 0: no parent',  
  `style_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Style override for specific node',  
  `effective_style_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Style override; pushed down tree',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`node_id`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `node_name_unique` (`node_name`,`node_type_id`),  
  KEY `parent_node_id` (`parent_node_id`),  
  KEY `display_order` (`display_order`),  
  KEY `display_in_list` (`display_in_list`,`lft`),  
  KEY `lft` (`lft`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=304 ;
```

**`xf_post`**

```
CREATE TABLE `xf_post` (  
  `post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `post_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `message` mediumtext NOT NULL,  
  `ip_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `message_state` enum('visible','moderated','deleted') NOT NULL default 'visible',  
  `attach_count` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `like_users` blob NOT NULL,  
  `warning_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `warning_message` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`post_id`),  
  KEY `thread_id_post_date` (`thread_id`,`post_date`),  
  KEY `thread_id_position` (`thread_id`,`position`),  
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3123657 ;
```

**`xf_thread`**

```
CREATE TABLE `xf_thread` (  
  `thread_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,  
  `reply_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `view_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `post_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `sticky` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `discussion_state` enum('visible','moderated','deleted') NOT NULL default 'visible',  
  `discussion_open` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',  
  `discussion_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',  
  `first_post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `first_post_likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  `last_post_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `last_post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `last_post_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `last_post_username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `prefix_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`thread_id`),  
  KEY `node_id_last_post_date` (`node_id`,`last_post_date`),  
  KEY `node_id_sticky_last_post_date` (`node_id`,`sticky`,`last_post_date`),  
  KEY `last_post_date` (`last_post_date`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=76301 ;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can just do it in two queries. First fetch `thred` joined with `post` and in second `select * from xf_node WHERE node_id IN (list of nodes from firs query)`

Comment: This question seems better suited for [dba.se]. Voting for migrating it.

Comment: @piotrekkr This query is generated by XenForo using its models, so splitting into separate queries is not an option for me

Comment: @AndriyM It seems to me more a server-related issue, so if there is a better place to post this please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes order by clause in mysql will use temp table to sort results. For large data it can take a lot of time. Avoid using "order by desc" and sort data outside mysql.

Comment: Unfortunately ordering in PHP is an option, as there are 70 000+ threads returned without ordering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted, does not use any column from the post table, and it is not used in filters either. I would say you could drop that.

For the DESC ordering (which is time consuming): that could be tweaked into ASC, if you create an additional column, and fill it with

```
MAX_INT - unix_timestamp(thread.last_post_date)
```

That will give you smaller numbers for later threads, so an ASC order on that gives you really a DESC on time.

In that case also new indexes have to be created.

(The example is in pseudo language, check mysql for syntax)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The query is actually using data from both tables, and many more tables and fields, I have just posted simplified version, to show that even simple join itself causes the problem. The idea with sorting the way you suggest may help, however it is not a global solution for me as, as I am not writing the query itself, but just using XenForo models to get this data, and this query is generated by the system, which I would like not to alter.

Answer (score 0):

If the two `thread` columns (`node_id` and `first_post_id`) are not nullable and you have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints that you can trust, from `thread(node_id)` towards `xf_node (node_id)` and from `thread(first_post_id)` towards `xf_post(post_id)`, you can remove the joins to `xf_node` and `xf_post`:

```
SELECT thread . *
FROM xf_thread AS thread
WHERE thread.node_id IN (295, 296, ..., 271)
ORDER BY thread.last_post_date DESC
LIMIT 10 ;
```

An index on `(last_post_date, node_id)` might help as well, to improve efficiency:

```
ALTER TABLE xf_thread 
  ADD INDEX last_post_date_node_id 
    (last_post_date, node_id) ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no foreign keys defined in XenForo tables, and there is an index already that contains all columns of last_post_date and node_id. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statements in your question. So we know datatypes, indexes and engine.

Comment: The question is edited now and includes create table statemnets. Thanks.

Comment: You do **not** have an `(last_post_date, node_id)` index.

Comment: There is a KEY `node_id_last_post_date` (`node_id`,`last_post_date`)

Comment: Exactly. The order is different so the keys are different and can benefit different queries. try adding my suggestion.

Comment: When I have added the key in different order, phpmyadmin showed warning that multiple indexes are defined for same columns, so I have removed it without trying the query. Will try it soon and update here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maby try something like this one and show your results in comment:

```
SELECT thread . *, post.*
FROM xf_thread AS thread
INNER JOIN xf_node AS node ON (node.node_id = thread.node_id)    
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM xf_post AS p
    WHERE p.post_id IN (
        SELECT t.first_post_id FROM thread t WHERE t.node_id IN ('295', ...)
    )
) AS post ON thread.first_post_id = post.post_id
WHERE thread.node_id IN ('295', ...)
ORDER BY thread.last_post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I have tried this query and it was very resource-intensive, simply hanging MySQL server